# How to output dependency files in Yosys (gcc -MMD equivalent)?

Tags: makefile, yosys

Is there a command for Yosys, which creates a dependency file equivalent to the gcc option -MMD? (This option outputs a small Makefile fragment, which lists all files included by the compilation unit. See [Using g++ with -MMD in makefile to automatically generate dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855386/using-g-with-mmd-in-makefile-to-automatically-generate-dependencies))

Background: I try to build a Makefile, which synthesizes a verilog project using Yosys. The project uses a single top verilog file, from which other verilog dependencies are included. To do that I use the following make rule, which works very well:

```
$(HARDWARE_BLIF_FILES): $(SUITE_OBJ_DIR)/%.blif : $(SUITE_SUPPORT_HARDWARE_DIR)/%.v
    $(HARDWARE_YOSYS) -q -p 'read_verilog -I/path/to/hwlib $<' -p 'synth_ice40 -blif $@'
```

Since I don't want to mention the other verilog files in the Makefile explicitly, I would like to use a dependency file. This would allow to detect changes applied to any of the dependency files and trigger a recompilation.

---

Thanks to the new yosys -E option added by Clifford, I could change the Makefile rule above as follows:

```
-include $(HARDWARE_BLIF_DEP_FILES)

$(HARDWARE_BLIF_FILES): $(SUITE_OBJ_DIR)/%.blif : $(SUITE_SUPPORT_HARDWARE_DIR)/%.v
    $(HARDWARE_YOSYS) -q -E $(SUITE_OBJ_DIR)/$*.v.d -p 'read_verilog -I/path/to/hwlib $<' -p 'synth_ice40 -blif $@'
```

Now, the blif file is generated, whenever one of the implicitly referenced Verilog files changes.

Comment: Hi Alexander, I'm looking into implementing this in my Makefile. Is your project publicly available on Github, could you share the link?
I'm trying to generate the .v.d file from a "top.v" . Do I need to explicitely add `include macros in each module.v file so that yosys -E can detect them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A feature like this has now been added to Yosys git head (a96c775). Simply add `-E <depsfile>` to your yosys call to generate a dependencies file.

Comment: Hi Claire, when I run yosys -E top.v.d top.v, the generated file starts with ":" followed by the name of all explicitely included modules (.v/.vh...). SHouldn't there be something on the left hand side of the ":" ?
On the LHS should be the target, right?